# Wanted to eliminate the repetition in the classes created to reduce duplication

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, code-duplication

Can someone help me on how to eliminate repetition to reduce duplication score on the below classes created in the code? I needed to reduce the code to improve the coding standards no idea how to go about it please someone help me.

Wanted to eliminate the repetition in the classes created to reduce duplication

```
class SubmissionFieldsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = submissionfields
        fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            if hasattr(instance, key):
                if key == "email_embedd":  # special case
                    instance.email_embedd = json.dumps(value)
                else:
                    setattr(instance, key, value)

    #     instance.ef_underwriter_decision = validated_data.get('ef_underwriter_decision',
    #                                                           instance.ef_underwriter_decision)
    #     instance.ef_feedback = validated_data.get('ef_feedback', instance.ef_feedback)

    # NBI USE CASE
        if instance.ef_underwriter_decision == configur.get('decisions', 'non_binding_indication'):

        # enquiry Log
            dict_obj = temp_dict()

        # Update Submission table based on underwriter decision
            submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).update(email_status='active')
            submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).update(
            email_uwriter_decision=instance.ef_underwriter_decision)
            submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).update(
            email_today_mail=configur.get('mailstatus', 'nbi_mail_type'))
            instance.email_today_mail = configur.get('mailstatus',
                                                 'nbi_mail_type')
        # setting email_today maio to 0 for submission fields

        # CR7.1 Changes (FROM COMPLETED TAB TO PROCESSED TAB)
            submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).update(
            email_deleted=configur.get('mailstatus', 'nbi_mail_type'))

            temp_email_table = submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).values(
            'email_id',
            'enquiry_id',
            'email_sender',
            'email_subject',
            'email_broker',
            'email_outlook_date',
            'email_today_mail',
            'email_assigned_user',
            'email_deleted')

            for today in temp_email_table:
                for t in today:
                    dict_obj.add(t, today[t])

            if len(validated_data.get('ef_insured_name', instance.ef_insured_name)['name']) == 0:
                dict_obj.add('ef_insured_name', not_avbl)
            else:
                dict_obj.add('ef_insured_name', validated_data.get('ef_insured_name', 
                instance.ef_insured_name)['name'])

            if len(validated_data.get('ef_obligor_name', instance.ef_obligor_name)['name']) == 0:
                dict_obj.add('ef_obligor_name', not_avbl)
            else:
                dict_obj.add('ef_obligor_name', validated_data.get('ef_obligor_name', 
                instance.ef_obligor_name)['name'])

            if len(validated_data.get('ef_obligor_name', instance.ef_obligor_name)['country']) == 0:
                dict_obj.add('el_country_name', not_avbl)
            else:
                dict_obj.add('el_country_name',
                         validated_data.get('ef_obligor_name', instance.ef_obligor_name)['country'])

            dict_obj.add('enquirylog_limit', validated_data.get('ef_financials', 
            instance.ef_financials)['limit'])
            dict_obj.add('ef_underwriter_decision',
                     validated_data.get('ef_underwriter_decision', instance.ef_underwriter_decision))
            dict_obj.add('ef_decision_nty_fields',
                     validated_data.get('ef_decision_nty_fields', instance.ef_decision_nty_fields))
            dict_obj.add('ef_feedback', validated_data.get('ef_feedback', instance.ef_feedback))
            dict_obj.add('relation_id', validated_data.get('relation_id', instance.relation_id))
            dict_obj.add('enquirylog_status', 'active')
            dict_obj.add('enquirylog_pipeline', validated_data.get('ef_pipeline', 
            instance.ef_pipeline))

        # CR3.2 Primium and basis point addition
            dict_obj.add('broker_email_id', validated_data.get('broker_email_id', 
            instance.broker_email_id))
            dict_obj.add('premium', validated_data.get('premium', instance.premium))
            dict_obj.add('basis_points_decision',
                     validated_data.get('basis_points_decision', instance.basis_points_decision))
            dict_obj.add('basis_points', validated_data.get('basis_points', instance.basis_points))

            dict_obj.add('coverage', validated_data.get('ef_coverage', instance.ef_coverage)['coverage'])
            dict_obj.add('tenor', validated_data.get('ef_coverage', instance.ef_coverage)['tenor'])

            enquiry = enquirylog(email_id=dict_obj['email_id'],
                             enquiry_id=dict_obj['enquiry_id'],
                             coverage=dict_obj['coverage'],
                             tenor=dict_obj['tenor'],
                             email_subject=dict_obj['email_subject'],
                             relation_id=dict_obj['relation_id'],
                             email_broker=dict_obj['email_broker'],
                             email_outlook_date=dict_obj['email_outlook_date'],
                             enquirylog_limit=dict_obj['enquirylog_limit'],
                             email_assigned_user=dict_obj['email_assigned_user'],
                             email_today_mail=dict_obj['email_today_mail'],
                             ef_insured_name=dict_obj['ef_insured_name'],
                             ef_obligor_name=dict_obj['ef_obligor_name'],
                             el_country_name=dict_obj['el_country_name'],
                             ef_underwriter_decision=dict_obj['ef_underwriter_decision'],
                             ef_decision_nty_fields=dict_obj['ef_decision_nty_fields'],
                             ef_feedback=dict_obj['ef_feedback'],
                             enquirylog_status=dict_obj['enquirylog_status'],
                             enquirylog_pipeline=dict_obj['enquirylog_pipeline'],
                             email_deleted=dict_obj['email_deleted'],
                             premium=dict_obj['premium'],
                             basis_points=dict_obj['basis_points'],
                             basis_points_decision=dict_obj['basis_points_decision'],
                             broker_email_id=dict_obj['broker_email_id']
                             )
            enquiry.save()
```

Comment: This looks like it would be better suited to some other Stack Exchange site? anyway one thing I can spot is you have multiple statements like `submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).update(...)`, you could have simply written them as one statement `submission.objects.filter(email_id=instance.email_id).update(email_status='active', email_uwriter_decision=instance.ef_underwriter_decision, ...)`

Comment: Plus in that last gigantic `enquirylog(...)` if `dict_obj` is a dictionary and it only has the _required_ keys and no other, you could have simply written `enquirylog(**dict_obj)`

Comment: Your question _might_ be more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although please take a look at their help center and check their rules, etc. before posting.

Comment: Can I use this enquirylog(**dict_obj) instead of the entire enquirylog code block at the end